# Why does alt+5 bring me to tty?

Tags: kubuntu, tty, wayland

If I press alt+F5, I get to tty5. The former behaviour was alt+ctrl+f5. Now I need to use alt+f2 for running new applications and alt+f5 for maven update in eclipse.

- Why and when did then behaviour change?
- How do I revert  to old behaviour (ctrl is also needed)?

Thanks!

Running Kubuntu 18.04 LTS on default config (which is wayland afaik). But I don't thing this is related.

Comment: The default in Kubuntu 18.04 is **not** Wayland! Even the Kubuntu devs don't recommend it at this stage unless you really want to. But you are not alone: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071847/kubuntu-how-to-remove-altf-keybinding-to-switch-ttys

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/886593/alt-f4-switches-to-tty4 helps.

Comment: Specifically, https://askubuntu.com/a/929115/248158

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the linked answer. It shows a probable solution, but I have found the root cause in the mean time (which is why I created this entry as an answer). It is a hard bug. Please upvote it to raise the "heat counter": https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146

A probable solution is:

```
sudo dumpkeys | grep -v -E '^(\W+)alt(\W+)keycode.*Cons' | sudo loadkeys
```

I added those commands (without the sudo part) to a new rc5.d file so it does persist after a reboot.

I saw other people grepping only for left and right arrow, but in my case more keys are affected. See the bug report for more information.

HTH, and please don't forget to upvote!

Comment: Does anything like "I think either synergy or uinput could qualify as "some program left your keyboard in the wrong state" as mentioned in the kbd_mode docs." from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146/comments/41 apply in your case?

Comment: Well, I am using a laptop, so maybe yes. Where do I see this message?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. But it seems from reading the link to the bug you provided that some applications, `synergy` and `uinput` were mentioned, seem to mess with the keyboard state.

Comment: This worked for me as expected - adding to my rc5.d - thanks!